# Copying the entire contents of a text file into a character array variable

Tags: c, file

I have to place the contents of a text document called Bond.in into a character array variable.  I've tried several methods to save the contents of Bond.in into a character array, but the one that is below is the only one tha seems to work.  However, everytime I try to print the contents of the variable array using the my_getline function (a function we wrote in class that we have to use), it enters an infinite loop.  I can't figure out if this is because of the for loop that calls my_getline or if the contents of Bond.in aren't copying into text[] properly.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Also, let me know if I left out anything that would help.

```
/*   Include the standard input/output and string libraries             */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*   Define the maximum lines allowed in an input text and NEWLINE for getline funct.   */
#define MAXPATTERN 15
#define MAXWORDS 150
#define NEWLINE '\n'

/*   function prototypes                                */
void my_getline(char text[]);
int find_string(char text[], char pattern[], int length_text, int length_pattern);

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char text[MAXWORDS];
   int i = 0, j;
   char fileName[15] = "Bond.in";
   char pattern[MAXPATTERN], c;
   int length_text, length_pattern, count;

   fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("fopen failed.\n");
      return(-1);
   }

   while(feof(fp))
      text[i++] = fgetc(fp);
   text[i] = '\0';

   printf("%s has been copied.", fileName);

   for (j = 0; text[j] != EOF; j++)
   {
      my_getline(text);
      printf("%d  %s \n", j, text);
   }

   printf("Enter the pattern you would like to search for: ");
   scanf("%s", pattern);
   printf("\nYou have chosen to search for: %s\n", pattern);

   //printf("%s appears %d times in %s.\n", pattern, find_string(text, pattern, length_text, length_pattern), fileName);
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}

void my_getline(char text[])
{
   int i = 0;
   while ((text[i] = getchar()) != NEWLINE)
      ++i;
   text[i] = '\0';
}
```

**Bond.in**

```
    Secret agent Bond had been warned not to tangle with Goldfinger.
But the super-criminal's latest obsession was too strong, too dangerous.
He had to be stopped.
    Goldfinger was determined to take possession of half the supply of
mined gold in the world--to rob Fort Knox!
    For this incredible venture he had enlisted the aid of the top
criminals in the U.S.A., including a bevy of beautiful thieves from the
Bronx.  And it would take all of Bond's unique talents to make it fail--
as fail it must.
```

Comment: I don't understand what your program tries to do, and it's a very bad way to write a program, the first `while (feof())` loop and then the `for (; text[i] != EOF ;)` it does not ressemble the logic behind.

Answer (score 1):

You never put an `EOF` into `text`, so it isn't surprising that your loop never stops.  You *did* put a `'\0'` at the end, so your loop for printing should be looking for that.

Comment: It would be good to mention that `getchar()` or `fgetc()` return `int`s and thus the program could overflow `text[i]` which is also why `EOF` cannot be stored in `text`.

Comment: Even after changing
    for (j = 0; text[j] != EOF; j++)
to
    for (j = 0; text[j] != '\0'; j++) I'm still left with an infinite loop. Why isn't this condition being met?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
   fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("fopen failed.\n");
      return(-1);
   }

   while(feof(fp))
      text[i++] = fgetc(fp);
   text[i] = '\0';
```

reads zero bytes because `feof(fp)` is false right after the file is opened.

And this

```
void my_getline(char text[])
{
   int i = 0;
   while ((text[i] = getchar()) != NEWLINE)
      ++i;
   text[i] = '\0';
}
```

replaces everything in `text` with data read from `stdin`, until a newline is read in, thus overwriting everything you could have already read.

This will read the contents of a file and NUL-terminate it (assumes no NUL characters in the file contents, POSIX environment):

```
int fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY );
struct stat sb;
fstat( fd, &sb );
char *contents = calloc( 1, sb.st_size + 1 );
read( fd, contents, sb.st_size );
close( fd );
```

Error checking is left as an exercise.

Comment: I don't only need to read it's contents though. I also need to save it's contents into a character array

Comment: @PatMulvihill `char *contents  = calloc( 1, sb.st_size + 1 );` *is* a dynamically-allocated character array.  One that's big enough to hold the entire contents of the file - plus one byte for a terminating NUL character.